# Getting a strange result when comparing 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a pair of dictionaries in python: (both have exactly the same keys)

```
defaults = {'ToAlpha': 4, 'ToRed': 4, 'ToGreen': 4, 'ToBlue': 4,}

bridged = {'ToAlpha': 3, 'ToRed': 0, 'ToGreen': 1, 'ToBlue': 2,}
```

When I iterate through one of the dictionaries I do a quick check to see if the other dict has the same key, if it does then print it.

```
for key, value in defaults.iteritems():
    if bridged.get(key):
        print key
```

What I would expect to see is:

```
ToAlpha
ToRed
ToGreen
ToBlue
```

But for some reason, 'ToRed' is not printed. I must be missing something really simple here, but have no idea might might be causing this.

```
bridged.get('ToRed')
```

and

```
defaults.get('ToRed')
```

both work independently, but when iterated through the loop... Nothing!

Any idea's?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing - `0` evaluates false-y, which is why you should explicitly test for `None` **by identity** - `if bridged.get(key) is not None:`.

Comment: First thing first, `dict.get()` should return the values (so `int`s here) not the key. Also worth noting, `dict` are not ordered so it wouldn't necessarily follow the order you specified.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What if `None` is the actual value for the key? In this case it would be fine, but it's best to use solutions that work for every case. The `in` operator is clearly superior here.

Comment: @Shashank fair point; I'd assumed integer values, another sentinel would be required as the second argument to `dict.get` if `None` was a valid value. Membership testing is better, but doesn't quite tell the OP why their method failed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0` is false. Use `in` to check for containment.

```
if key in bridged:
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the if statement when 'ToRed' gets passed.

`if 0`

returns false, so the key is not returned.  Use

`if key in bridged`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when `key` is `ToRed`, then `bridged.get('ToRed')` will be 0.
So following will evaluate to **False**:

```
if bridged.get(key):
```

thereby not printing `'ToRed'`.

Instead of this, use the `in` operator.

**Using `in` the most pythonic way to check if a key is in a dictionary.**

So check using this:

```
if key in bridged:
```

Final code now becomes:

```
>>> for key, value in defaults.iteritems():
        if key in bridged:
            print key
ToAlpha
ToRed
ToBlue
ToGreen
```